# If condition for PHP to evaluate

Tags: php, operators, boolean-logic

i have following bit of code

> $cond = '0'; if($cond) echo $cond;
>
> $cond = '0 '; if($cond) echo $cond;
>
> $cond = '0 AND 0'; if($cond) echo $cond;

the first one only does what is expected the rest does not. how can these perform same behavior, Especially how can i evaluate the condition in the third case.

Comment: what are you expecting to happen?? i would expect them all to echo $cond

Comment: i am expecting that nothing should print on all those conditions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
if (intval($cond)) echo $cond;
```

But why would you want to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Just search for 0 in $cond with strpos

```
$cond = '0 AND 0';
$search = '0';

if (strpos($cond, $search) !== false) echo $cond;
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php

Answer (score 1):

First, I'll explain what is happening. In each case, you're testing a string, not a boolean expression. A non empty string always evaluates to `true` except if it can be converted to another type.

- `'0'` will be converted to the integer `0` and so to `false`
- `'0 '` will stay as string because of the space which explicitly says that it's a string, so is `true`
- `'0 AND 0'` is obviously a string and is `true` too

I don't know what exactly you're trying to achieve and if you need to handle other cases but what you seem to need is [eval() function](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php). As said in the documentation, its use is **very dangerous** so be sure of what `$cond` can be to avoid it if possible.

```
$cond = '0 AND 0';
if(eval('return '.$cond.';'))
    echo $cond;
```

Answer (score 0):

try for second one

```
 if ((trim($cond)){
   echo $cond;
    }
```